# Search for words by adding special characters between them

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database which has a column with some text that I would like to search.

Lets say a few of the text statements in the database are

1. Hi My name is XXX2 and I live in YYY ZZZ
2. My name is also written as XXX-2 and I live in YYY-ZZZ
3. Sometimes it is written as XXX 2 and I live in YYYZZZ

Lets us say now I want to search the MySQL database for statements containing "XXX2" or "YYY ZZZ" through a PHP script.

Using MySQL to search would only return statement 1). I want to return all three sentences.

One thing I am thinking is to generate all permutations of the search string in PHP and query the MYSQL database sequentially. Is this the best way to proceed? is there any ready made function in Php to generate such combinations?

Comment: why would it return the other 2? Line 2 and 3 contain neither "XXX2" nor "YYY ZZZ".  And tell us what you are doing to access the data.  Post your SQL for example

Comment: How many combinations will be there like this for your name? XXX2, XXX-2, XXX 2, X XX2, XX X2 etc?

Comment: @SajithNair I know the exact place where there would be a special charcter. so for XXX2 the only valid combinations are XXX 2, XXX-2, XXX2.

Comment: So you can replace the special character position with % and make a LIKE query like others has specified below

Comment: So it will become name LIKE 'XXX%2'

Comment: @SajithNair this would also match `XXX was talking like 2 hours` as `%` matches any number of characters on the other hand `_` inside [`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) requires the presence of a character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know which characters to expect between the word-parts you can use regular expressions to query your database. For your examples this would work:

Find variants of XYZ2:

SELECT
      *
    FROM `xytest`
    WHERE val RLIKE 'XXX[- ]?2';

Find variants of YYYZZZ:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM `xytest`
WHERE val RLIKE 'YYY[- ]?ZZZ';
```

This uses [MySQL's regular expression matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to allow an optional `-` or  between word parts.

If there can be more characters in between you could change `[- ]` to e.g. `[- _]` (also recognizes `_`) or `[^a-z0-9]` (every non-letter non-number). The `?` after the brace makes it's presence optional.

Sadly MySQL will not be able to tell you what matched, but you can feed the same regular expression to one of PHP's regular-expression engines if you need to know.

Finding either XXX2 or YYYZZZ:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM `xytest`
WHERE val RLIKE 'XXX[- ]?2|YYY[- ]?ZZZ';
```

or of course

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM `xytest`
WHERE val RLIKE 'XXX[- ]?2' OR val RLIKE 'YYY[- ]?ZZZ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the LIKE operator maybe

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    mycol 
LIKE 
    '%XXX%YYY%ZZZ%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search with 1 character variations, try following:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    mycol 
LIKE 
    'XXX_YYY_ZZZ'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE  'XXX%'
OR `column` LIKE  'YYY%'
```